# How to do 3 stars ? in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm looking for how to do 3 stars for the level , when the player finish the game if he did well in the game its give him 3 stars and so on... 
If anybody know how to do this , please inform me how to work with it and if there's any video that describe how to do 3 stars in unity please comment it.

That's what i want like this

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJP3e.png

Regards

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are actually asking. Are you looking to implement a system in a script which determines how many stars the player achieves? Or how to do a graphical presentation of the star system? Or what? You should modify the question so it's clearer what you're trying to achieve. And also include what you have tried before.

Comment: what does "did well" mean?

Comment: @Hilse didn't tried anything but i watched some tutorials and its not clear , check the question again i but a picture for what i want.

Comment: @yes if the player finished the level good by doing everything in the level

Comment: @Hilse Like angry birds game

Comment: well if "the player finished the level good by doing everything in the level" you already have the answer. if he did everything give him 3 stars, if he did, idk 75% he gets 2 stars and so on. imagine it like this, every task gets the player x points (you can scale that or just give 1pt per task) and the level has a total of y points. now you only need to do some basic maths to get how much of the tasks the player has fulfilled and display stars accordingly.

Comment: @yes Thanks bro , do you know any tutorial that's describe how to do it ? that's will be good.

Answer (score 0):

you must read about canvas (that deals with screen itself). After that you can create star images inside the canvas and change their scale from 0 to 1.